# Mikrotik Switch Trunk (Tag All) Port

Tags: networking, switch, vlan, mikrotik

Trying to configure switching on Mikrotik CRS125-24-1S.

- ether24 is connected to another switch port with tag all (trunk) mode activated
- ether23 is connected to my ESXi host

I just want to add this Mikrotik switch in the middle of the network path, no routing is needed. One example VLAN is 13.

I've tried adding the VLAN:

```
Flags: X - disabled, I - invalid, D - dynamic 
 #   VLAN-ID PORTS                                       SVL LEARN FLOOD INGRESS-MIRROR QOS-GROUP                                     
 0 D    4095 ether1                                      no  no    no    no             none                                          
             ether2                                     
             ether3                                     
             ether4                                     
             ether5                                     
             ether6                                     
             ether7                                     
             ether8                                     
             ether9                                     
             ether10                                    
             ether11                                    
             ether12                                    
             ether13                                    
             ether14                                    
             ether15                                    
             ether16                                    
             ether17                                    
             ether18                                    
             ether19                                    
             ether20                                    
             ether21                                    
             ether22                                    
             sfp1                                       
             switch1-cpu                                
 1        13 ether23                                     no  yes   no    no             none                                          
             ether24                                    
             switch1-cpu
```

Also the egress vlan tag:

```
[admin@MikroTik] /interface ethernet switch egress-vlan-tag> print
Flags: X - disabled, I - invalid, D - dynamic 
 #   VLAN-ID TAGGED-PORTS                                                                                                            
 0 D    4095
 1        13 ether23                                                                                                                 
             ether24                                                                                                                 
             switch1-cpu
```

The terms on RouterOS are somehow different, I know I'm missing something. Don't know what.

But communication is not happening. I know routing is working because right now I have a Cisco Switch to test and doing that on Cisco works well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No need VLAN adding. Just create a bridge and attach ports 23 and 24 to that bridge. All traffic including tagged one will pass.

```
/interface bridge add name=bridge-trunk protocol=none
/interface bridge port add bridge=bridge-trunk interface=ether23
/interface bridge port add bridge=bridge-trunk interface=ether24
```

OR/If you have performance issues (CRS125 CPU going up when several 100'Mbps are passing), you can use the inboard switch chip, faster than bridge.

```
/interface ethernet set [ find name=ether24 ] master-port=ether23
```

Then eth24  will be enslaved to eth23 and the two ports will act like a simple switch.

If it does not work, just reset-config the CRS125 with "no-default" option to wipe out all messy config and re-do the previous commands.